Search text in vscode using a popup like intellij
Is it possible to configure VSCode to display a modal when searching for a text inside any file? I'm looking for something similar to Jetbrains' Find in Files shortcut(default shortcut Ctrl+Shift+F)

For the close voters, What i'm asking isn't answered in the linked question. I'm asking for a modal like the intellij find in files. The linked question doesn't have anything like this
